# How does my code know which .dll it adress?

Tags: c++, dll, header

I have a sample.dll file and a corresponding sample.h header file. I add both into references and include the header in my c++ code. How this program knows that header file corresponds that particular .dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this program knows that header file corresponds that particular .dll?

It doesn't!

Basically, when you compile your program, the compiler will see the declarations inside `sample.h` and make a note for the linker to find the corresponding definitions later on if needed.

When it's time to link your program, the linker will look through all the DLLs, libraries, and other object files you're linking with and try to find the definitions that corresponds to all the declarations the compiler found in files like `sample.h`, in your case it's going to find those in `sample.dll` because that's where they were compiled.

If the linker doesn't find a matching definition, or if it finds several, then it's an error and linking will fail.
And that's why your program doesn't need to know what header corresponds to what particular .dll, because [there is only have definition allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) for each of these declarations, so it can just look everywhere until it finds it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. But when you call a function defined in the header, it then looks for something that defines that function. If `foo.h` declares `foo()`, and `foo.dll` contains a definition of `foo()`, then it all works.